# How to replace default "FrontPage" in Fitnesse to some other test folder/wiki page

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

Suppose we run fitnesse server on port 8080 by java -jar fitnesse-standalone.jar -p 8080 and then we open fitnesse by localhost:8080 in browser, it points to default fitnesse "FrontPage". I have test/wikipages folder located at same/different place which I want to point to by default. I mean, I want fitnesse to point to my test folder by default instead of pointing to "FrontPage" so that when I hit the url localhost:8080 or I click on fitnesse logo (on right top on fitnesse wiki page), it shows/points to the test folder name instead of FrontPage.

Please help me understand how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't make another page the default. BUT you can replace the content of the page with what you want.

I usually put a link to my test suite there. But you could also make it the root suite for your tests.